# Woocommerce reset password does not save the new password

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am updating an e-commerce website and I use the Woocommerce login, the problem is when resetting the password, below I explain the behavior:

1- When I press Recover Password, it directs me to a page where I must enter an email

2- After entering the email, I get an email "Password Reset Request" with a link

3- This link directs me to a page with a form where I must enter the new password

Herein lies the problem, when I enter the new password and press "Save" it does nothing, nor does an email arrive, nor does it redirect me to the login page and when I try to log in with my new password it gives me a user error or an incorrect password. Please someone more experienced to explain to me what this behavior is due to

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this CSS code below, there is probably an error message on the page that is being hidden

```
.page-id-1154 .woocommerce-message, .page-id-10 .woocommerce-message { 
    display: block !important; 
}
```

For further assistance you can check this link:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/207131/reset-my-password-links-to-itself-page-refreshes